# when taking pictures with my d70 i get red stripes

Tags: troubleshooting

I get red stripes in the lcd screen and when I down load the pictures it is the same thing. wondering if the camera is no longer working or a sensor or something.
try to reboot my using a suggestion from other post it did not work

Comment: Can you post a link to an example photo?

Comment: Red stripes of always the same size, location, redness and stripiness in every picture?

Answer (score -2):

Have you taken the battery out for 24 hours, and then rebooted the camera?

On the D70, I am not sure that a factory reset does anything other than change settings, so that may not help.

Sounds like the display hardware.  If so, the service depot is your only practical option.

Comment: OP states, ”when I down load the pictures it is the same thing".  If accurate, that rules out a problen isolated to the display.

Comment: Thanks for helping me better understand the OP.  I read it to be when he viewed images from the memory.  I agree if the images are corrupted upon transfer off the camera, it is not the display.  If the OP clarifies  things, I will withdraw this answer.